# SQL, combine results and return with 2 decimal places

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with employee information including sales persons and the other with transactions. I need to query both and return a calculated commission of 2.5%, first and last names. What I have returns this but to three decimal places instead of two and is it possible to combine the results to return one for each person?

```
SELECT fName, lName, Amount_Due * 0.025 AS Commission
FROM EMPLOYEE, "TRANSACTION"
WHERE  EMPLOYEE.Eid = "TRANSACTION".eID
```

Result

| fNAME | lNAME | Commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | 20.00 |
| Jane | Doe | 12.00 |
| Jack | Jones | 10.000 |
| Jack | Jones | 15.000 |
| John | Doe | 12.000 |
| John | Doe | 14.00 |

Thanks for any help

Comment: Take a look at GROUP BY and SUM ( assuming you want one total commission per person)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like exactly what I want. I'll look into that.

Comment: What DBMS/database are you using? @KrisEllison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these **sql** math functions `round()`, `sum()` and aggregation `GROUP BY` to achieve your requirements.

```
SELECT e.fName, e.lName, round(sum(t.Amount_Due * 0.025), 3) AS Commission
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN "TRANSACTION" t on e.Eid = t.eID
GROUP BY e.lName, e.fName
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to add the SUM later in the query instead of in SELECT.